# Laravel get wrong table while querying

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I try to insert some data to the new table that I have create but laravel choose wrong reverse table. Instead of job_contract get contract_job.

> QueryException in Connection.php line 636:
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'job.contract_job' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `contract_job` (`contract_id`, `job_id`) values (2, 4))

I am new in laravel. Is anyone know the way that laravel defines the names of tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quote about the relation table:

> The role_user table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains the user_id and role_id columns.

In your case it would be contract_job with contract_id and job_id.

And another quote:

> However, you are free to override this convention. You may do so by passing a second argument to the belongsToMany method:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_roles');
```

So I guess you only need to pass the correct table name as second param to your belongsToMany method(s) like this:

```
//in your Contract model
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Job', 'job_contract');
```

and

```
//in your Job model
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contract', 'job_contract');
```

Quotes from [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: I hope that's what was causing your problem. Take care

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about what the `Model` name of your related php file is.

Usually, the table would be like

if your model name is`User` the table name should be `users` !

For tables like `customer_details` , the model name should be `CustomerDetail`

But you can also select a particular table with the model using

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'my_flights';
}
```

In this example, you can see that the table name by default should be `flights` but you can change it to whatever you want like this !

Answer (score 1):

A way to fix this is to tell the Model wich table to use (Put in your model):

```
protected $table = 'job_contract';
```

This way you force the Model to use that table and not some other table
[See more here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models)